# Scope de injectable en angular

Tags: angular, servicio, scope

Tengo un componente con una dependencia de un servicio, el cual le paso por el contructor

```
 constructor( private cultureService: CultureService){ }
```

Este Culture Service es en realidad una interface y en el modulo tengo un Factory que dependiendo del valo de una variable, me carga uno u otro service.

```
    const cultureFactory = (calculatorService: CalculatorService) => {
  if (environment.unitsCulture === 'miles') {
    return new AmericanService(calculatorService);
  } else {
    return new EuropeanService(calculatorService);
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ConverterComponent, CultureConverterComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, ConverterRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CultureService,
      useFactory: cultureFactory,
      deps: [CalculatorService]
    }
  ]
})
```

Cuando cargo por primera vez el componente, funciona correctamente y me lanza el service que corresponde dependiendo del valor de la variable, pero las siguientes veces ya no me recarga el servicio, y me lanza siempre el que se haya cargado la primera vez, independientemente de si despues la variable ha cambiado de estado...

mi prigunta es si, al igual que en nestJS por ejemplo, hay alguna menra de cambiar el scope de un provider en angular para que me lo instanci cada vez que sea requerido.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cambiar la implementación para tener un solo servicio que contenga ambas implementaciones y que tenga un método que permita cambiar la cultura actual.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CultureService {
  private american: AmericanCulture;
  private european: EuropeanCulture;

  private currentCulture: Culture;

  get culture() {
    return this.currentCulture;
  }

  changeCulture(units: 'miles' | 'kilometers') {
    this.currentCulture = units == 'miles' ? this.american : this.european;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.american = new AmericanCulture();
    this.european = new EuropeanCulture();
    this.currentCulture = this.american;
  }
}
```

Para usarlo serí así:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private cultureService: CultureService) {}

  changeCulture(units: any) {
    this.cultureService.changeCulture(units);
  }
  calculate() {
    alert(this.cultureService.culture.calculate(4));
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7h9928?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: muchisimas gracias por perder tu tiempo en mi duda! Ya habia contemplado algo similar para asimilarlo, pero como estoy empezando, la duda era sobre todo didactica. Es decir, para saber si podria hacerse lo de instanciar mas de una vez un servicio. pero me has ayudado un monton!!